# pull-right class is not pulling right instead dropping down other buttons

Tags: html

sorry guys im new to code so something like this might seem like a stupid question but this is the first time i cant find any answers online.

basically like the title says the pull-right class is not pulling right instead it is dropping down other buttons. take a look at my codepen test file https://codepen.io/goceman86/pen/xdeoQv

heres the html code... so far i only tried the pull right function on the last button

```
<header>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-
BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" />
</header>

<div class="container-fluid">

  <button class="btn-primary mebtn"><a href="#" class="btnfont" style="font-family:'Lobster'; font-size:1.8em;">InHo Jo</a></button>

  <button class="btn-primary ambtn"><a href="#" class="btnfont" style="font-family:'Lobster'; font-size:1.8em;">About me</a></button>


  <button class="btn-primary profbtn"><a href="#" class="btnfont" style="font-family:'Lobster'; font-size:1.8em;">Profile</a></button>



  <button class="btn-primary cmbtn"><a href="#" class="btnfont pull-right" style="font-family:'Lobster'; font-size:1.8em">Contact Me</a></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please poste all your code in S.O. without links to other sites.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `.pull-right` from the link in last button, You do not need it here. But if you want `.pull-right` class name for javasript/jquery, You can add this style:

```
.pull-right {
    float: none !important;
}
```

But if you want your last button (not it's inner link) is in right of the page, add `float: right;` to the button.

```
<button class="btn-primary cmbtn" style="float: right;"><a href="#" class="btnfont pull-right" style="font-family:'Lobster'; font-size:1.8em">Contact Me</a></button>
```

Comment: still not working for me   ```<button class="btn-primary cmbtn"><a href="#" class="btnfont" style="font-family:'Lobster'; font-size:1.8em; 'float:right'">Contact Me</a></button>
</div>```

Comment: In your code you forgot this: `style="float: right;"` for button. Please copy the last line of my answer and paste it exactly in your code (instead of your last button).